# HTTP POST data content-length

Tags: http, post

I want to understand how the POST data is treated when in transit.

If I send a JSON object as POST data, the content-length of the request body is equal to the number of characters in the stringyfied version of the JSON object.

Question :

- Does this imply that the POST data is always treated as a string when being sent ?
- The content length of the post data is actually the count of the characters as each character is treated as to hold 1 byte and accordingly should respond to the POST data limit of the server i.e, if I have the limit odf 1MB of post data on server then the max content-length can be only 1024*1024?

Comment: each character takes one byte? Are you sure about that?

Comment: @JulianReschke: That is the question. This is so as i uploaded a string of length 5 characters and content-length turned out to be 5. Also assuming and that since the content-length is the decimal representation of the OCTETs that means it is in bytes.

Comment: The assumption that one characters maps to a single byte in general is incorrect. Read about Unicode in general, and the various ways to encode it into byte sequences, such as UTF-8.

Comment: @JulianReschke: This is exactly my question too.

Comment: @JulianReschke: I want to know how HTTP treats POST data in transit

Comment: HTTP transmits whatever you send. It's not a protocol question, but a question about the library/API/component you use to make the request. You may want to expand your question to make clearer what you want to know.

Comment: @JulianReschke : My question is :  How can I calculate that my POST data is within the permissible POST data limit set at server before sending the POST call in java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an HTTP request takes the form of a sequence of bytes, i.e. a string. What else would it be? HTTP doesn't know about JSON; it doesn't know your bytes are to be later interpreted as JSON; even if it did, it would not care! It is a *transport* protocol.

And yes, if there is a limit of 1MB POST data, then you can only send 1MB worth of POST data.

Comment: Why should a sequence of bytes only mean characters? numbers (45) can also be stored as numbers. What I observe is that 4 and 5 are treated and stored as one byte characters each.

Comment: Also, when I wanted to equate 1MB of data, I meant that each characters is being treated as of 1 byte. How does this work with UTF-16 etc. EDIT : I just read browsers communicate using UTF-8 only. I might be missing on some basics. Please bear with me

Comment: @BhumiSinghal No, things can only be stored as bytes.